# Oracle developer tools for VS 12c not working with VS 2010

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework, odac, odt.net

I have a project which is developed in VS 2010 and when I try to update the edmx file it is not at all working.

I have uninstalled and installed the ODT many times but nothing is working. while installing also the installation window does not detect VS 2010 
It is listing VS 2015 and VS 2017 but not at all listing VS 2010.

[image]

I can update the edmx model from VS 2015 but when I try the same from VS 2010 it is showing an error message like below

[image]

I have removed the connection string from web.config and added a new data connection server explorer->Data connections .

Now the error is not coming and it is asking me to create a new connection( The connection which I created via server explorer is not at all listing) and I cannot find Oracle database option in the new connection window also

[image]

VS 2010,2015,2017 are installed in my machine.

I have installed ODTwithODAC and ODT for VS 2015 for resolving this issue but no luck.

Any thoughts on this issue ? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by installing `ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit` version
([link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html))

The steps I have followed :

1. Remove all oracle related entries from Environment variable path
2. Restart the machine
3. Stop all the services which are starting with ora or Ora
4. Run regedit.exe and delete the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` key. This key contains registry entries for all Oracle products.
5. Delete any references to Oracle services left behind in the following part of the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Ora*` It should be pretty obvious which ones relate to Oracle.
6. My machine is 64 bit one So I have deleted the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE` key also from the registry.
7. Restart machine
8. Delete the "C:\app" directory(while installing if you given other name then you need to delete that)
9. Delete the "C:\Program Files\Oracle" directory.
10. Empty the contents of my temp directory
11. Empty my recycle bin.

**Note: By following the steps from 1 to 11, we can uninstall any oracle products successfully.**

> Update : 29-03-2019 :
>
> If we have installed ODAC with ODT new versions( 12.2 +) then we need
> to do couple of other steps to complete the full uninstallation of
> oracle products
>
> Close all instances of Visual Studio
>
> For Visual Studio 2015:
>
> Please delete registry key
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Packages{D601BB95-E404-4a8e-9F24-5C1A462426CE}
>
> For Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise:
>
> CD into ( from command prompt)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
>
> execute:
>
> VSIXInstaller.exe /skuName:Enterprise /skuVersion:15.0 /quiet /admin
> /uninstall:Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0
>
> For VS2017 Professional:
>
> CD into
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE
>
> execute:
>
> VSIXInstaller.exe /skuName:Pro /skuVersion:15.0 /quiet /admin
> /uninstall:Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0
>
> For VS2017 Community:
>
> CD into
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE
>
> execute:
>
> VSIXInstaller.exe /skuName:Community /skuVersion:15.0 /quiet /admin
> /uninstall:Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0
>
> Note:
>
> Above examples assume that VS2017 is installed at C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017.
>
> If you installed VS2017 into a different location, CD into the
> appropriate location and then execute the VSIXInstaller.exe command.

Update : 2nd August 2019

> If you have already installed odp.net components then there might be
> an entry in the machine config.
> For safe side its better to remove it from there also.
> Do not remove any item which is starting with System. which is not part of the odac components. ( Example : system.data.oracleclient)

12. Download the ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit and install it.
13. If you have any changes in the `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` then apply it